# Attempted import error: 'Provider' is not exported from 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store} >
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Above is my index.js code. but it is showing error like

```
./src/index.js
Attempted import error: 'Provider' is not exported from 'react-redux'.
```

in the react-redux file of app the code is

```
import Provider from './components/Provider';
import connect from './components/connect';
import { ReactReduxContext } from './components/Context';
import { useDispatch, createDispatchHook } from './hooks/useDispatch';
import { useSelector, createSelectorHook } from './hooks/useSelector';
import { useStore, createStoreHook } from './hooks/useStore';
import shallowEqual from './utils/shallowEqual';
export * from './types';
export { Provider, ReactReduxContext, connect, useDispatch, createDispatchHook, useSelector, createSelectorHook, useStore, createStoreHook, shallowEqual };
```

It is showing that `Provider` is exported. So there should  not be any error

Here https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1826 he says that **Something is wrong with your build tooling**
can anybody help?

Comment: How are you building your application? Do you have your own webpack or you're using something different?

Comment: Can you show a reproductible example please ? with code sandbox for example

Comment: I don't see ```store``` being imported in your index.js code. This might not solve your issue but like the above comment mentions you will have to share a more reproducible example to help debug further.